# Wrapping non serializable type with serializable function

Tags: java, scala, serialization

Given:

```
trait SomeTypeNotSerializable
trait ValueProvider[T] extends java.io.Serializable {
  def get: T
}
```

Is `ValueProvider[SomeTypeNotSerializable]` serializable? Is there a way to get around non-serializable issue by wrapping an object with a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `Serializable` according to the rules, but *if you store that `T` as a non-transient field* it'll fail at runtime. If the `T` is transient or not backed by a field (e.g., created at each call to `get`), then you should be fine, although I'm still curious why you're wanting to serialize a service object, which isn't the usual practice.

Comment: Its not a service object that I am trying to provide, its a third party object badly designed and non serializable.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see `ValueProvider[SomeTypeNotSerializable]` would not be serializable in this case.

This can be checked with the below sample code, which when run prints:

```
testString is Serializable
st2 is Serializable
```

Main Class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        NonSerializableThing nst = new NonSerializableThing();

        SerializableThing<NonSerializableThing> st = new SerializableThing<>();
        st.set(nst);

        if(nst instanceof Serializable) { // always false
            System.out.println("nst is Serializable");
        }

        if(st.get() instanceof Serializable) {
            System.out.println("st is Serializable");
        }

        String testString = "testString";
        SerializableThing<String> st2 = new SerializableThing<>();
        st2.set(testString);

        if(testString instanceof Serializable) { // always true
            System.out.println("testString is Serializable");
        }

        if(st2.get() instanceof Serializable) {
            System.out.println("st2 is Serializable");
        }

    }
}
```

Other Types:

```
public class NonSerializableThing {

    NonSerializableThing() {}
}

public class SerializableThing<T> implements java.io.Serializable {

    public T t;

    public SerializableThing() { }

    public void set(T t) {this.t = t;}
    public T get() {return t;}

}
```